# Why is the image in div not displayed in full-size?

Tags: css, images

A couple of days ago everything was good, but now the image is not displayed in full-size. This seems like [an old bug](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/image-size-3).

Here's what failed to me:

- Adding a custom CSS: `img .size-full {width:900px;}`
- Adding `<?php $content_width = 900 ?>` to my theme's `functions.php` file
- Looking at `wp-includes/media.php`, but cannot find `$max_width=500`
- Using the plugin `Regenerate Thumbnails` to regenerate the thumbnails
- Uploading the images via FTP

I don't have this problem with another site. Is this because of the host? I would like to know what is happening, and how to fix it. The link to the page that has an image that cannot be in full-size is [here](http://lightninged.cards/just-why/).

Comment: You should be a bit more specific. Under what circumstances won't full size image show? What is the php code that is supposed to generate this image? Is any javascript or a plugin involved?

Comment: Not enough information for us to go on. CSS is invalid, Can you show more code.

Comment: @cjbj I don't know. I set everything up fine, then suddenly this appears. Where I can find that php code?

Comment: @Sisir what code are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, but without knowing the relevant code (or even a link to the site in question) we here can do nothing but offer wild guesses.

Comment: @cjbj so do you know where is the relevant code? I have added the link

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but `img` probably does not have a child element with the class `size-full`. The class is probably on the `img` itself. So it should probably be `img.size-full` without a space. Which would make this a CSS problem and not a WordPress problem.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ that's all I can do with the info you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Visiting your site I must conclude that this is a simple case of wrong css (and hence not a WordPress problem).

You have all your content in a `div` with class `container`. In your `bootstrap.min.css` you set the width of this container as 1170px. In `style.css` you define `max-width:100%` on images. So no matter how you define the width of your image, it is always scaled so it fits into 1170px.

Comment: so should I edit the `bootstrap.min.css`, or the `style.css`, or use a custom css? And for the sake of knowledge, where should I find the php code?

Comment: The php is somewhere in your theme files. If this is not your own theme you should make a child theme to put your changes in.

Comment: thanks, but is there a quick (and safe) way to do the fix instead?

Comment: The quick and dirty one is editing the css files.

Comment: But if the theme is updated you lose your edits.

Comment: I put it in the custom css, so it will be fine. I've tried `div img { width: 1540px;}` but it doesn't work

Comment: If you don't really know how css works, the best approach is to open the development Window in your browser and try things until it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43943/discussion-between-ooker-and-cjbj).

Comment: Sorry, we are talking very trivial css skills here. You should be able to do this on your own.

Comment: I understand that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

`img .size-full {width="900";}` is not valid CSS. Use either
`img .size-full {width:900px;}` for fixed site/exact width or
`img .size-full {max-width:100%;}` for fluid/responsive

*Update, as per Florian, and of course remove the space as well, as img is an "empty" tag - no descendant possible: `img.size-full`*

Answer (score 1):

It's not amazingly obvious from your question which images you are talking about but I would suggest that **if** it is all images in the content of the page linked too that you simply add a css rule for it. Something like the following:

```
.entry-content img { height: auto; width: 100% }
```

This would force the image to be the same width as it's container and stretch it out to 915px wide on your desktop breakpoint.